# Passing input files into a transformer

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I want to be able to pass my input files and output files into this program with a seperate main method. My intentions are to access this through a GUI.

```
public class SimpleTransform {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException, TransformerConfigurationException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {  
        // Use the static TransformerFactory.newInstance() method to instantiate 
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("demiprocess.xsl")); 
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource("Anzer.xml"), new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("lee.xml")));
        System.out.println("*The result is in birds.out ***");
    }
}
```

This is what I tried but I keep getting errors:

```
public class Simple {
    private String xmlFile ;
    private String xslFile;
    private String  outputFile;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Simple
     */
    public Simple(String xmlFile, String xslFile,String outputFile) {
        this.xmlFile = xmlFile;
        this.xslFile = xslFile;
        this.outputFile= outputFile;
    }

    public String SimpleTransform() throws TransformerException,TransformerConfigurationException,FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String mystring = "";
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslFile));
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xmlFile), new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)));
        return mystring = "***The result is in birds.out *****";
    } 
}
```

i get this error "file:///C:/Users/Abiodun/Desktop/New%20system/new%20system/demiprocess.xsl; Line #1; Column #10; stylesheet requires attribute: version"

Comment: What are the errors you keep getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are missing the version attribute in your XSL file declaration. Does it start with something similar to this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

Comment: it starts with                                                  xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

Comment: Working perfectly when i added that. Thank you!